# Integrating Vaadin GWT Polymer Elements into an existing GWT project without usign Maven, Ant or Gradle

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea, gwt-polymer, gwt-2.8

I have an older GWT project that was based on GWT 2.7.0 and I need to integrate the Vaadin Polymer elements in it. There some problems though:

- Vaadin only lists guides on how to build a gwt polymer project using dependency managers like Maven, for various reasons I must keep the project clean and not use such a dependency manager, right now it's only managed through Ant.
- I tried copying libraries from a polymer project (THE ONLY project that works out of the box is the GWT polymer starter kit. The tutorial on the GWT site is broken/outdated!). What I copied was *jsinterop-annotations-1.0.0.jar*, *jsinterop-annotations-1.0.0-sources.jar*, *colt-1.2.0*, *ant-1.6.5* and *vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.2.3.0.jar*. This caused a lot of headache, because compiling without GWT 2.7.0 gives some weird error in the GWT console:

> Exception: com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Unexpected error during visit.
>   ...
>   Caused by: com.google.gwt.dev.shell.HostedModeException: JSNI rewriter found reference to non-existent field in a field reference or java method tear-off: @java.util.ArrayList::array at com/vaadin/polymer/Polymer.java(490)

- ... but compiling with GWT 2.8.0-rc1 gives the following error in the build process:

  > java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

No matter how big I set the -Xmx variable( the heap size), it's still showing up.

- The recommended GWT version 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT.jar is nowhere to be found, not even on the maven repository...

I've literally tried going 3-4 pages deep on google search trying to solve this problem. Has anyone attempted to use this library without the dependency managers?

P.S. I'm using IntelliJ Idea, if that's useful information...

Comment: There is already the RC2 of GWT 2.8 available now (also on mvn: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-servlet). Perhaps you can check this. Where exactly you found the jars mentioned above. On the github site of the gwt polymer starter kit project I don't see information about it. What Xmx values did you test?

Comment: You can try building GWT Polymer Elements yourself. You need to use gwt-api-generator, There are guidelines on the their github page:https://github.com/vaadin/gwt-polymer-elements. There is also a download link if you do not want to use maven. You should note that it's not compatible with GWT 2.7